# getElementById returning null in the code but working in the console

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using javascript to fill a html form from saved values.

I have to check a table of checkbox so I am using a php script to generate an js function that I execute later.

```
    for($i = 0; $i < count($day_pos) - 1; $i++)
{
    if ($day_pos[$i + 1] - $day_pos[$i] > 7)
    {
        if ($day_pos[$i + 1] - $day_pos[$i] > 8)
        {
            echo ("document.getElementById(\"".$rdv_days[$i * 2]."\").checked = true;");
            echo ("\ndocument.getElementById(\"".$rdv_days[$i * 2 + 1]."\").checked = true;");
        }
        else if ($uf_hours[$day_pos[$i] + 5] == "sur")
        {   
            echo ("document.getElementById(\"".$rdv_days[$i * 2]."\").checked = true;");
        }
        else
        {
            echo ("document.getElementById(\"".$rdv_days[$i * 2 + 1]."\").checked = true;");
        }
    }
    echo("\n");
}

echo ("</script>");
```

Everything before in this function is working just fine.

$rdv_days is an array with all the id of the checkbox.

When I load the form page, it throws me an error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null

The error is at the line where I do the getElementById in my js function.

But when I, using the debugger console in chrome, break on the line where it fails and evaluate the expression in the console, it works just fine.

I have checked if the string for the id doesn't contain any hidden characters and it does not.

I really don't understand why it's not able to find the element.

Thanks for your time

Edit :

Here is the code generated (just a portion, the webpage is 4000 lines)

```
document.getElementById("rdvMatLun3").checked = true;
document.getElementById("rdvApLun3").checked = true;
```

And here is the table associated with it later in the page

```
<td>
<input type='checkbox' id='rdvMatLun3' name='rdvMatLun3' value='1'/>RDV</td>
</td>
```

Comment: Most likely the element does not exist at the point in time where your JS code is executed.

Comment: Not sure about this but try giving space after `\n` here `\ndocument.getElementById`

Comment: Thats how I call this function :

    <body onload="javascript:initialisation_formulaire(0);">

Comment: @user3484799 Perhaps you should put that kind of stuff in the question. Can you show the resulting HTML from your PHP?

Comment: could you print $rdv_days[$i * 2] on screen in order to see if this is null? if yes, that part of code doesn't help

Comment: Added the generated page, and I checked $rdv_days, it's not null

Comment: could you then move step forward and print in alert what is given with getElementById? is it null?

Comment: It's giving me null, I did console.log of it and it gave me null too

Answer (score 0):

Execute code before document body ends. It makes you sure that all website data finished loading.

```
(function() {
   // your code here

})();
</body>
```

Comment: Why allways jQuery for such simple things?

Comment: And the webpage is loaded, I am setting values of a bunch of lists and it is working, so the elements are loaded

Comment: @epoch the first version of the answer was using jQuery.

Comment: @rekire I don't see any edit history, so I assume that's the first version up there by @cyan. That's an [anonymous method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#JavaScript) being invoked immediately after declaration.  You can do this without jQuery as an experiment to verify this works: in your address bar, you can execute arbitrary javascript by typing `javascript:` followed by a command, which could very well look like `javascript:(function(){alert('This works');})();`

Comment: @JustinBell you know that you can edit as much as you like a answer within the first 5 minutes?

Comment: @rekire You mean and not have it appear as though you did?  No, I didn't :toes ground sheepishly: